# Struggling to get my CURL dropdown request to populate answers using php

Tags: php, ajax, php-curl

Unfortunately I am not that great when it comes to this area of IT but have been given the task of creating a drop down list that uses AJAX, PHP and CURL to retrieve data from CURL for post code information from the following URL:

http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeCountryInfoJSON?formatted=true&&username=mlord&style=full%27

Below is my code for php however cannot get the for loop to cycle through the data in the url and feed back the correct answer depending on the drop down selection. Any help would be appreciated!

Code below:

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    $url = 'http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeCountryInfoJSON?formatted=true&&username=mlord&style=full' . '&countryName=' . $_REQUEST['countryName'] . '&username=mlord&style=full';
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result,true);    
    
    $country = null;
    

for($i = 0; $i < count($decode["geonames"]); $i++){

                if($_REQUEST["countryName"] == $decode["geonames"][$i]["countryCode"]){

                                $country = $decode["geonames"][$i];

}

}

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode['geonames'];
    
     
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 
    
    

?>
```

The script running is:

```
$('#btnRun').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "php/getPostalCodeInfo.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                countryName: $('#countryName').val(),
                
            },
            success: function(result) {

                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

                if (result.status.name == "ok") {

                    $('#txtcountryCode').html(result['data'][0]['countryCode']);
                    $('#txtcountryName').html(result['data'][0]['countryName']);
                    $('#txtnumPostalCodes').html(result['data'][0]['numPostalCodes']);
                    $('#txtminPostalCode').html(result['data'][0]['minPostalCode']);
                    $('#txtmaxPostalCode').html(result['data'][0]['maxPostalCode']);

                }
            
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // your error code
            }
        }); 
    
    });
```

Index.html shown below with no CSS currently.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Task</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Task">

    </head>
    <body>

        <select id="countryName">
            <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
            <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
            <option value="AT">Austria</option>
            <option value="AU">Australia</option>
        </select>

        <button id="btnRun">Run</button>

        <br><br>

        <div id="divResults">
            
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        Country Code: 
                    </td>
                    <td id="txtcountryCode">
                        
                    </td>

                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        Country Name: 
                    </td>
                    <td id="txtcountryName">
                        
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        Number of Postal Codes: 
                    </td>
                    <td id="txtnumPostalCodes">
                        
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        Minimum Postal Code: 
                    </td>
                    <td id="txtminPostalCode">
                        
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        Maximum Postal Code: 
                    </td>
                    <td id="txtmaxPostalCode">
                        
                    </td>

                </tr>

                
            </table>

        </div>

        <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you **need** to use PHP & curl for this? The remote site has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header so you could simply use javascript

Comment: Hello, yes need to use both PHP and curl. Currently the code grabs the first option from my drop down list but the for loop is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

From the above code it is unknown how the `select` menu is initially populated so it appears that you are attempting to send and process an ajax request based upon a selected value in the `select` menu and subsequent button click. As the FORM is not shared and my assumption might be incorrect as to how your app functions I put together an alternative version where the JSON data is fetched by cURL and the `select` menu is then populated by the AJAX callback that initiated the entire process ( @page load )

The endpoint that you have elected to target with the `curl` request ( namely: `postalCodeCountryInfo` ) appears to ignore the `countryName` parameter that you have supplied and returns the complete, unsorted list regardless. That knowledge helped shape the following as there is no point sending a fresh request to the remote API with different `countryName` values only to receive the exact same response - it would make more send to issue a different request and process that response in the callback perhaps.

```
<?php

    # basic curl wrapper function to send GET requests  
    function curl( $url=false ){
        $curl=curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, trim( $url ) );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/10.0' );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );
        $res=(object)array(
            'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
            'status'    =>  curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE )
        );
        curl_close( $curl );
        return $res;
    }
    
    # this is the proxy script that will fetch the json data, from the provider, in response to the ajax request.
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action']=='fetch-json' ){
        
        
        # prepare the parameters of the request
        $format='JSON';
        $endpoint='postalCodeCountryInfo';
        $args=array(
            'formatted' =>  true,
            'username'  =>  'mlord',
            'style'     =>  'full'
        );
        $baseurl='http://api.geonames.org/';
        
        # build the final endpoint url
        $url=sprintf('%s%s%s?%s', $baseurl, $endpoint, $format, http_build_query( $args ) );

        
        # make the reequest
        $res=curl( $url );
        if( $res->status==200 ){
            /*
                Because the data is returned in a non-sorted manner
                we apply our own sorting (alpha) so that the final
                select menu is ordered as expected.
                
                convert json to an array for sorting
            */
            $data=json_decode( $res->response, true );
            
            # determine the column for sorting by
            $name=array_column( $data['geonames'], 'countryName' );
            # sort the data
            array_multisort( $name, SORT_ASC, $data['geonames'] );

            # re-sequence in the original format
            $data=array( 'geonames' =>  $data['geonames'] );
            
            # success.. send the json data back to the ajax callback
            http_response_code( 200 );
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            # send json data
            exit( json_encode( $data ) );
        }
        
        #something went wrong...
        http_response_code( $res->status );
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>GeoNames</title>
        <style>
            body{ display:flex; flex-direction:column; font-family:monospace; width:100%; height:100vh; padding:0; margin:0;}
            body,body *{ box-sizing:border-box}
            form{ margin:2rem auto; padding:0.5rem; border:1px solid black; border-radius:0.5rem; background:aliceblue;}
            label{ display:flex; flex:1; margin:1rem 0; padding:1rem; border:1px dotted grey; border-radius:0.5rem; justify-content:space-between; background:white; }
            label input, label select{ margin:0; padding:0.25rem; }
            [type='button']{ padding:1rem; margin:1rem 0; width:100%;text-align:center;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='lookup' method='post'>
            <label>Country: 
                <select name='country'>
                </select>
            </label>
            
            <label>Name: <input type='text' name='countryName' /></label>
            <label>Code: <input type='text' name='countryCode' /></label>
            <label>Total: <input type='text' name='numPostalCodes' /></label>
            <label>Min: <input type='text' name='minPostalCode' /></label>
            <label>Max: <input type='text' name='maxPostalCode' /></label>
            
            <input type='button' name='sub' value='Submit' disabled />
        </form>
        <script>
        
            const d=document;
            const f=d.forms.lookup;
            const oSel=f.country;
            
            let fd=new FormData();
                fd.set('action','fetch-json');
            
            // send request to PHP proxy script to fetch the data using curl
            fetch( location.href, { method:'post', body:fd } )
                .then( r=>r.json() )
                .then( json=>{
                    Object.keys( json.geonames ).forEach( key=>{
                        // get the record
                        let obj=json.geonames[ key ];
                        
                        // create a new option element
                        let option=new Option( obj.countryName, obj.countryCode );
                        
                        // assign dataset attributes taken from the record to the `option`
                        Object.keys( obj ).forEach( param=>{
                            option.dataset[ param ]=obj[ param ]
                        })
                        
                        // add the option to the menu
                        oSel.appendChild( option )
                    });
                    
                    return true;
                })
                .then( bool=>{
                    oSel.addEventListener('change', e=>{
                        // find the currently selected `option` and it's associated dataset attributes
                        let ds=e.target.options[ e.target.options.selectedIndex ].dataset;
                        
                        // iterate through this option's dataset and populate form elements with same name as attribute
                        Object.keys( ds ).forEach( key=>{
                            f[ key ].value=ds[ key ];
                        });
                    });
                    
                    return true;
                })
                .then( bool=>{
                    f.sub.disabled=false;
                    console.info('Affirmative, Dave. I read you.');
                })
                .catch( console.warn )
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Using the original HTML (with script tags changed/removed) and incorporating the same logic applied in the answer above whereby the remote API is queried just once perhaps the following will help you solve your problem.

Where your AJAX function is sending requests to `php/getPostalCodeInfo.php` these answers send the request to the same page - it is trivial to take the PHP code from here and add to / replace the code within that named PHP file.

```
<?php


    function curl( $url=false ){
        $curl=curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, trim( $url ) );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/10.0' );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );
        $res=(object)array(
            'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
            'status'    =>  curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE )
        );
        curl_close( $curl );
        return $res;
    }
    
    
    /*
        Regardless of any countryName parameter specified in the request URL this
        endpoint returns ALL results. So it makes sense to make only 1 request.
        Querying of the JSON response can & will be done in javascript.
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action']=='fetch-json' ){
        $baseurl='http://api.geonames.org/';
        $format='JSON';
        $endpoint='postalCodeCountryInfo';
        $args=array(
            'formatted' =>  true,
            'username'  =>  'mlord',
            'style'     =>  'full'
        );
        $url=sprintf('%s%s%s?%s', $baseurl, $endpoint, $format, http_build_query( $args ) );
        $res=curl( $url );
        
        if( $res->status==200 ){
            http_response_code( 200 );
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            exit( $res->response );
        }
        
        http_response_code( $res->status );
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Task</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Task">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- 
            force the "change" event to work for all option elements immediately
            by adding a hidden option that is pre-selected but that cannot be re-selected.
            
            The HTML is otherwise unchanged.
        -->
        <select id='countryName'>
            <option selected hidden disabled>Please Select
            <option value='AD'>Andorra
            <option value='AR'>Argentina
            <option value='AT'>Austria
            <option value='AU'>Australia
        </select>
        
        <button id='btnRun'>Run</button>
        
        <div id='divResults'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align='right'>
                        Country Code: 
                    </td>
                    <td id='txtcountryCode'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align='right'>
                        Country Name: 
                    </td>
                    <td id='txtcountryName'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align='right'>
                        Number of Postal Codes: 
                    </td>
                    <td id='txtnumPostalCodes'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align='right'>
                        Minimum Postal Code: 
                    </td>
                    <td id='txtminPostalCode'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align='right'>
                        Maximum Postal Code: 
                    </td>
                    <td id='txtmaxPostalCode'></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            /*
                The two form elements of interest -
                the `select` and `button` which will 
                be used for event listeners.
            */
            let oSel=document.getElementById('countryName');
            let oBttn=document.getElementById('btnRun');
            
            let fd=new FormData();
                fd.set('action','fetch-json');
            
            /*
                function to iterate through **some** of the
                JSON data until a match is made. Once that 
                match is made, query the DOM to find the
                TD element that has the ID almost the same
                as the json key and add text to it.
                
                So that the same function can be used to
                process both the "change" and the button "click"
                events the "el" parameter refers to "Select"
                menu so that we can read it's value and compare
                to the JSON value in the "some" loop.
            */
            const callback=(el,json)=>{
                json.some(obj=>{
                    if( obj.countryCode==el.value ){
                        Object.keys( obj ).forEach( key=>{
                            let td=document.querySelector( `#divResults table td#txt${key}` );
                            if( td )td.textContent=obj[ key ];
                        });
                        return true;
                    }
                }); 
            }
            
            /*
                One does not even need do the AJAX request if the PHP Proxy
                script happens to be the same page. Otherwise, do the AJAX
                request to the PHP Proxy script to fetch the data from the
                GeoNames API. This need only be done ONCE!!
                
                If you "comment-out" the `callback(e.target,json)` call
                within the `oSel` event handler then only the button
                will trigger the json lookup and subsequent populating 
                of table cells.
            */
            fetch( location.href, { method:'post', body:fd } )
                .then( r=>r.json() )
                .then( data=>{
                    
                    let json=data.geonames;
                    
                    oSel.addEventListener('change', e=>{
                        callback( e.target, json );
                    });
                    
                    oBttn.addEventListener('click',e=>{
                        callback( oSel, json );
                    })
                })
                .catch( alert )
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I had a drop down box selector where the user could pick from four text options and then hit an enter button to populate the matching data from the curl link.

Comment: The code shown above ought to help you solve the issue but if you update the question with the appropriate HTML that might help more

Comment: Your code, if I understand correctly, will send a curl request using the value from the dropdown menu as the `countryName` parameter and you then hope to match the result once the curl request has retrieved the data? That is, if you'll forgive me, not the way to do it. As I mentioned - the particular endpoint you have chosen to use will return **all** pieces of data regardless of the `countryName` parameter you specify in the request.

Comment: You will end up making effectively the same request each and every time when you really only need to fetch the data once ( as per my example code ) - subsequent selections from the dropdown will work with the already fetched json data and no further HTTP requests are needed. With your code there are two each time - the ajax request and then the curl request.

Comment: Having issues with my machine currently but I will grab the HTML code. Thank you for your help and description on this.

Comment: I have now attached the Index.html code to the bottom. Currently there is no CSS as I was planning to add that in later on.